# Recommended font size for Titles and subtitles on A4 print outs

Tags: fonts, print-design

I'm making some printable resources for schools and am wondering what the recommended font size would be for the titles and subtitles of these pages please? These would be printed on A4, and for schools in the UK.
Thanks

Comment: This all depends  upon the message and desired impact. There's no "standard" anywhere.

Comment: Hi Preeti, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the font and it's use but I would recomend the following:

18pt - header
14pt - titles
11pt - body